# Logout if user is logging from another computer

Tags: c#, winforms

My WinForms application's authentication works by registering a session on a PHP website using an `HttpWebRequest`.

I want each user to authenticate on just one computer. So when a user logs in to my application from computer A and successively from computer B, they should be forced to log out from computer A.

How to receive a response to logout on computer A when this user logs in on computer B?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, as you don't keep a connection open, and it's unidirectional too (client -> server). So the server can never call back saying "this session is no longer valid".

In order to do this, you need to use a bidirectional connection (where the server can push messages to the client), which can be done in many ways but requires altering both client and server drastically. Take a look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr).

The easy way would be to add a polling mechanism where you check every N seconds whether the current session is still valid, and if not, notify the user and close your application.

Comment: like Yahoo Messenger, i think it dont check every N seconds while it have thousand concurrent user

Comment: No, that's what I said in my second paragraph, you need an active, bidirectional connection between client and server, which is less ideal using HTTP. How to implement this is too broad to explain in an SO answer, but take a look at SignalR.

Comment: @user3809000 not sure what is your comment about - "you need to use a bidirectional connection" is already part of answer... If you need more answers - search for "http long poll" will give you plenty of links for implementations with just regular HTTP.